# Manually loading application context to write getBean() in spring boot application

Tags: spring

In a spring application, we write like this to get a bean through manually loading spring application context.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/applicationContext.xml");
JobLauncher launcher=(JobLauncher)context.getBean("launcher");
```

How to do the similar thing in spring boot ?
Being a newbie...need help

Answer (score 25):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);//init the context
        SomeClass myBean = app.getBean(SomeClass.class);//get the bean by type
    }
    @Bean // this method is the equivalent of the <bean/> tag in xml
    public SomeClass getBean(){
         return new SomeClass();
    }

    @Bean 
    public MyUtilClass myUtil(SomeClass sc){
         MyUtilClass uc = new MyUtilClass();
         uc.setSomeClassProp(sc);
         return uc;
    }
}
```

You can also your xml file to declare the beans instead of the java config, just use `@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})`

Edit: To answer the comment: Make the util class a spring bean(using @Component annotation and component scan or the same as `SomeClass` shown above) and then you can @Autowire the bean you like. Then when you want to use the Util class just get it from the context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
But for my case, I have an Util class somewhere located in my application.Now from that class I want to get a particular spring bean through loading the application context..What should be my approach ?

Comment: Or how to access the same applicationcontext reference in the main configuration class from other java util class in the same application ?

Comment: When do we require a manual ApplicationContext creation/configuration?

Comment: @PratikAmbani By "manual creation/configuration", do you mean using `@Bean` annotation instead of `@Component` annotations? If so - you have to use that when you don't own the class, that you want to create a bean from (e.g. if you want to create a bean of type String, you cannot go and modify the `String` class in JDK, you have to use `@Bean` in `@Configuration` class). Also I would use `@Bean` for classes that are kind of unique for the app. For types of beans that are declared many times (like services, repositories and controllers) - use the `@Component` and it's sub annotations.